# Angular 2. How correctly get inner ControlGroup from outer ControlGroup?

Tags: angular

I have the follow code, that validate the registration form and add error message, if invalidate data have been entered:

```
this.registerForm = _fb.group({
        // email: new Control(this.registerContact.email,
        //         Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])),
        emails:_fb.group({
            email: new Control(this.registerContact.email,
                Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])),
        }),

        passwords:_fb.group({
                            password: new Control(this.registerContact.password,
                Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])),
                            repeat_password: new Control(this.registerContact.repeat_password,
                Validators.required)},{
                            validator:checkRepeatPassword})
    });
```

And i need to get ***password*** and ***repeat_password*** from ***this.registerForm*** .
Now I use the following code:

```
...
 onValueChanged(data: any) {
    for (let fields in this.formError) {
        // console.log('fields: '+fields);
        for(let field in this.formError[fields]){

            //  console.log('      field: '+field);
        if (this.formError.hasOwnProperty(fields)) {

            let innerContol = this.registerForm.controls[fields].controls[field];

            let hasError = innerContol.dirty &&!innerContol.valid;
                console.log('hasError?:'+hasError)
            this.formError[fields][field] = '';
            if (hasError) {

                for (let key in innerContol.errors) {
                       if(field=='repeat_password'){
                    // console.log('repat_error:'+key)
                }

                    if (innerContol.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        console.log('   >>>outer repeat_password error!'+innerContol.value);    

                        this.formError[fields][field] += this._validationMessages[field][key] + ' ';
                         console.log('   >>>add follow errorMessage:'+this._validationMessages[field][key]); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, it's work, but i have the red underline in this method

> let innerContol = this.registerForm.controls[fields].***controls[field];***

with warning:
***property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'***

Maybe there is a better way to get ***password*** and  ***repeat_password*** ?

There is a link to github:

https://github.com/ProximaHaiz/Angular_2_book_library/blob/master/app_ts/registration/registration.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NB7fxRYeZDKVNabwQmrN?p=preview)

```
this.registerForm.controls.passwords.controls.password;
```